# Determine the limiting behaviour of $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine the limiting behaviour of $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}}$

Used L'Hopitals to get $\;\dfrac{(x^6+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{x^2 \sqrt{x^4+1}}$ but not sure what more i can do after that.

Comment: As $x \rightarrow \infty$ the fraction looks more and more like $\frac{\sqrt{x^4}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6}} = \frac{x^2}{x^2} = 1$

Comment: The LHR works poorly in general on rational functions which involve radicals.  Notice, for instance, that the factor $\sqrt{x^4 + 1}$ migrated to the denominator on the first pass (and the other radical is now in the numerator).  Repeated applications of l'Hopital will simply cause these radicals to volley back and forth between numerator and denominator.  To resolve limits such as these, you will have more success with the methods described by the responders here.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use L'Hospital's Rule, take the $6$-th power of the expression. We get
$$\frac{(x^4+1)^3}{(x^6+1)^2}.\tag{$1$}$$
Those nasty roots are gone.

Now expand and use L'Hospital's Rule a dozen times.  Better yet, **imagine** expanding and using L'Hospital's Rule a dozen times. The top expands to $x^{12}+ \text{lower degree terms}$. The bottom expands to $x^{12}+ \text{lower degree terms}$.  It we use L'Hospital's Rule $12$ times, all the lower degree stuff will die, and we will be left with $1$, in the cumbersome form $\frac{12!}{12!}$. So the limit is $1$. Thus the limit of the original expression is $\sqrt[6]{1}$.

But then again, once we see that the leading terms of the two polynomials are the same, the limit is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried *dividing* the original numerator and denominator each by $x^2 = \sqrt{x^4} = \sqrt[3]{x^6}\,$? This is a good example where algebraic manipulations are easier to use than is using L'Hopital.

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt[\large 3]{x^6+1}}\cdot \frac {1/\sqrt{x^4}}{1/\sqrt[3]{x^6}} =\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+1/x^4}}{\sqrt[\large 3]{1+1/x^6}}=\frac{\sqrt 1}{\sqrt[\large 3]{1}}=1
$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}} = \dfrac{x^2 \sqrt{1+1/x^4}}{x^2 \sqrt[3]{1+1/x^6}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1+1/x^4}}{\sqrt[3]{1+1/x^6}}$$

Comment: Minor mistake, here - should be $1+1/x^4$ under the square root on the numerators on the right.

Answer (score 3):

$$ {\frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}}\sim {\frac{\sqrt{x^4}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6}}}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Dividing numerator and denominator by $x^2$ gives
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}{\frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}}=\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^{-4}}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^{-6}}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt[3]{1}}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4 + 1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}$$

Mutliply top and bottom by $\frac{1}{x^2}$

$$lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^4 + 1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}} = lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^4}{x^4} + \frac{1}{x^4}}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^6}{x^6}+\frac{1}{x^6}}}$$

$$= lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^4}}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x^6}}} = \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt[3]{1}} = 1$$